# Indexed view in Sql Server 2005 Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, indexed-view

I tried to add an index on a view in Sql Server 2005 an I got this error: "Cannot create index on view 'AllAssignmentNotes' because the view is not schema bound."

I didn't want to put too much information here as it might be overload. Just wondering if anyone could give me some help.

I went to the url the error gave me and got me nowhere. The full error is below.

I know you can't make give a real answer because I haven't given you all the information, my apologies.

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Create failed for Index 'IX_AssignmentId'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.4035.00&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Create+Index&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

Cannot create index on view 'AllAssignmentNotes' because the view is not schema bound. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1939)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.4035&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=1939&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Comment: This article explains schema binding in detail. http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1610

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as the error says, you can't have an index on a view that isn't schema bound. To schemabind the view use

```
create view with schemabinding.
```

all tables referenced int the view must be fully quallified with the schemaname, i.e. dbo.table, not just table

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you created your view WITH SCHEMABINDING then its possible its the connection settings these SET options must be set to ON when the CREATE INDEX statement is executed:

```
ANSI_NULLS 
ANSI_PADDING 
ANSI_WARNINGS 
ARITHABORT 
CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL 
QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS
```

The NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT option must be set to OFF.

Comment: Sql Server should give a descriptive error such as "incorrect settings: 'ANSI_NULLS" in those cases, never a  Error 1939

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with indexed views was major pain since they were introduced. Rules to actually make a view that supports indexing are very strict and error messages are useless.

You should check BOL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432(sql.90).aspx